# What is a term that means "to force into a particular form"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm looking for a term that describes "forcing into a particular form", "forcing into looking like something else", or even "forcefully fitting into a category"

Ex:

"We (word) the function/statement/etc. into this particular form *so that* we can make statements about it using what we already know"

Comment: The metaphorical "shoehorning" might work.  Pigeon-holing might be what you're looking for.  Rubricate is a bit of a stretch, but it could work.  How about circumscribe?

Comment: I feel like "hamfist" used to work here, but I'm not sure it's still used this way.

Answer (score 3):

To borrow from programming terminology, [to coerce](http://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/coercion) or [to cast](http://cplus.about.com/od/glossar1/g/castdefinition.htm) might fit.

> We can coerce an adjective into a noun by adding a -ness ending to it, which may be understood even if, technically, it isn't the correct noun form.
>
> We cast expressions into variables to save our hands when writing equations.

Or simply even convert

> We convert the function into this particular form so that we can make statements we already know.

Comment: [Refactor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring) could also be useful in a programming context.

Answer (score 2):

I think the word [*mold*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/mold) would suffice in your sentence. As a verb, it means:

> to work into a required shape or form; shape.

*We **mold** the function into this particular form so that we can make statements about it using what we already know.*

Works for me.

Answer (score 1):

The previously-suggested words *[cast](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cast#Verb)* and *[manipulate](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/manipulate#Verb)* are often used in contexts like your sample sentence; for example,

> We cast the statement into form *X* so what we already know about *X* readily applies.”

Other words used in such a context include:
• *[normalize](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/normalize#Verb)*, “To format in a standardized manner, to make consistent. [eg] We'll need to **normalize** these statements before we can compare them”
• ***[canonicalize](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/canonicalize#Verb)***, “To convert (data) into canonical form”, where  *[canonical](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/canonical#Adjective)* means 
 “prototypical” or  “according to recognised or orthodox rules” or  “stated or used in the most basic and straightforwardly applicable manner [eg] the reduction of a linear substitution to its canonical form”.  Note,  *[canonicalize](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/canonicalize#Verb)* is a hyponym of *[normalize](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/normalize#Verb)*.

Answer (score 0):

Warp, twist, distort, transform, mutate, modify, bend.

When someone tries to modify the question so that the answer they have already chosen seems to work, we say, "Don't try to fit the question to the answer," or "Don't try to make the question fit the answer." Perhaps that will give you something to work with.

Comment: The phrase [_Procrustean bed_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procrustes) comes to mind.

Comment: "Contort" maybe.  Or "pervert".

Answer (score 0):

How about "put"?

"We put the statement into this particular form so that we can make statements about it using what we already know."

Doesn't work if by force you mean it isn't really a natural fit.

Answer (score -1):

> [***manipulate***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/manipulate): to change by artful or unfair means so as to serve one's purpose
>
> "We ***manipulate*** the function/statement/etc. into this particular form so that we can make statements about it using what we already know."